# how to manage user's SSO session invalidation in WSO2identity server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We'r using WSO2 Identity Server 5.1 for SAML SSO authentication.
is there any solution that can be display all sessions a user that do login from different device but i know are for same user. this means that for an user  exist some SP sessions that are not share at login. because login from different location(browser or device).

for example an user from workstation W1, established many SSO login via do login some application in same browser and we have some SP sessions so as W1_SP_SESSION_1, W1_SP_SESSION_2, W1_SP_SESSION_3 then same as do in workstation w1, the same user login with some app from workstation W2. then we have W2_SP_SESSION_1, W2_SP_SESSION_2, W2_SP_SESSION_3. Now we want to display all sessions exit for the same user. Is exits any feature or solution in WSO2 IS that i can get these SP sessions?

thanks a lot for your cooperation

Comment: if we can get and display SP sessions list for an desired user, with some info so as SP's issuer name, then can select one of them from SP session list and send at least a logout request for selected SP session and other shared SP sessions with it?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 doesn't have the capability to display all the authenticated sessions relevant for a particular user.

But with IS 5.3.0 (in [RC3](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wso2.org/msg64065.html) state at this time) has that capability. Please refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Terminating+User+Sessions) draft documentation for further information.

Hope that answers your question.